# Veracode XSS on empty String value

Tags: javascript, jsp, xss, veracode

After Veracode scan passed. I have reported XSS problem with CWE ID 80 for XSS vulnerability in my jsp:

```
<%@ attribute name="styleId"%>
...
document.getElementById("${styleId}").value=""; (XSS here)
```

I can not understand what is the problem where? Do I have to escape empty string? Or styleId or Both?
Do I have to use EASPI.encodeForHTML ??

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that styleId can introduce [XSS which to break the j](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.233_-_JavaScript_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_JavaScript_Data_Values)s.
So you have to escape the styleId with the rules for js. 
SO I add in my custom tag library
in **util.tag**

```
<function>
        <name>escapeJavaScript</name>
        <function-class>org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils</function-class>
        <function-signature>java.lang.String escapeJavaScript( java.lang.String )</function-signature>
    </function>
```

then

```
<%@ attribute name="styleId"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="util" uri="http://tags/util" %>
...
document.getElementById("${util:escapeJavaScript(styleId)").value="";
```

And the problem was fixed after next scan.